# My controller couldnt save physical file path in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, file-io, controller

I tried to update file to physically via my controller. But my controller save in local (actually Visual Studio run) perfectly but when I tried to publish and setup to on my server and use `www.mywebsite.com` then controller couldn't save to path without an error.

My scenerio is like this:

1. In client side onReady js method, I get physical root path from my database (this is work both side, no problem i watching debug console). My physical path like this: `\\192.168.1.1\MYFILE-1.1`
2. I pass to value with POST method file and root path via Model
3. In a controller side, I create timestamp for a file name, and combine more path file. Like this my controller:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult SavePhysicalPath(FileModel model)
   {
        //create timestamp of file name
         string filesMimeType = MimeTypesMap.GetMimeType(model.FormFile.FileName);
         string filesExtType = MimeTypesMap.GetExtension(filesMimeType);
         string fnTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmssffff");
         string edittedFileName = fnTimeStamp + "." + filesExtType;
         string edittedFmAndSubPath = "MyDocs\\OtherFiles\\" +edittedFileName ;
         var savingRootPath = "";
           savingRootPath =model.FileFolderPath; // FileFolderPath is string get from view "\\192.168.1.1\MYFILE-1.1"

          try
          {
               string SavePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), savingRootPath, edittedFmAndSubPath );

               using (var stream = new FileStream(SavePath, FileMode.Create))
               {
                   model.FormFile.CopyTo(stream);
               }

               stringOutput = "OK";
               return Json(stringOutput);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
                stringOutput = "ERR";
                return Json(stringOutput);
                throw;
          }
   }
   ```

Comment: First of all you need logging

Answer (score 0):

if there is no directory, then create one.

```
bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(SavePath);

if (!exists)
   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SavePath);
```

or you can create one in manually on server.